# How to write recursive union alls in PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table of pairwise-related numbers in a table `related_entities` like this:

```
| column_a | column_b |
| -------- | -------- |
| 100000   | 100001   |
| 100001   | 100002   |
| 100002   | 100003   |
...
| 100099   | 100100   |
| 100100   | 100101   |
```

How does one write a query that generates a table like this:

```
| column_a | column_b |
| -------- | -------- |
| 100000   | 100001   |
| 100000   | 100002   |
| 100000   | 100003   |
...
| 100000   | 100100   |
| 100000   | 100101   |
```

Further explanation: 100000 is related to 100101 (across 100 nodes). The number of maximum related nodes is unknown. Practical need — we have a table that relates 2 people to one another. There are an unknown number of total relationships.

For a table with a maximum of 3 (A-B and B-C) related nodes, it's pretty easy:

```
select *
from related_entities

union all

select r1.column_a, r2.column_b
from related_entities r1
join related_entities r2 on r2.column_a = r1.column_b
;
```

I just can't figure out how to write this in an efficient manner where maximum nodes are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is exactly the right method to get started with recursive queries when one is not used to them.

From your query, all you have to do now is add a CTE and use it instead of `related_entities r1`. You have built the 1st step of your recursion; doing so will cause it to execute in a loop.

```
WITH RECURSIVE MyRecursiveCTE AS (
select *
from related_entities
/* Add WHERE column_a = ... here if needed */

union all

select r1.column_a, r2.column_b
from MyRecursiveCTE r1
join related_entities r2 on r2.column_a = r1.column_b
)
SELECT * FROM MyRecursiveCTE
```

Of course, you can also do `r2.column_b = r1.column_a` to browse the hierarchy from the bottom up instead of from the top down.

---

To the above, I could add you currently seem to have no protection against loops. You may want to add a column as to protect yourself about infinite recursion.

```
WITH RECURSIVE MyRecursiveCTE AS (
select 1 AS level, *
from related_entities

union all

select 1+r1.level, r1.column_a, r2.column_b
from MyRecursiveCTE r1
join related_entities r2 on r2.column_a = r1.column_b AND level < 50
)
SELECT * FROM MyRecursiveCTE
```