# How to avoid prohibited outer join in recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which represents acyclic dependencies between objects:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dependencies
(
    obj_id        bigint,
    depended_upon bigint NULL
);
INSERT INTO dependencies
VALUES
    (1, NULL), -- 1 is not depended upon by any other object
    (2, 1),    -- 1 depends on 2
    (3, 4),    -- 4 depends on 3
    (3, 2),    -- ... and so does 2
    (4, NULL); -- 4 also is not depended upon by any other object
```

I'd like to determine the order in which I would have to prune objects so that no dependencies are violated, starting from the leaves. For this example, that result would look like this:

| Object ID | Prune step |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

Each object is pruned in the first step in which no other object depends on it.

I've tried to do this with a recursive CTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE deletion_order(obj_id, step) AS (
    SELECT obj_id, 0
    FROM dependencies
    GROUP BY obj_id
    HAVING COUNT(depended_upon) = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dependencies.obj_id, step + 1
    FROM dependencies
             LEFT JOIN deletion_order ON dependencies.depended_upon = deletion_order.obj_id
    WHERE deletion_order.obj_id IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM deletion_order
ORDER BY step;
```

But Postgres complains:

> [42P19] ERROR: recursive reference to query "deletion_order" must not appear within an outer join

How can I accomplish this without an outer join? Note that the format of `dependencies` is flexible, if it needs to change to accommodate the solution.

Comment: There's no need to include (1, null) and (4, null). This table represents edges, not nodes.

Comment: You're right, but it makes it easy to ensure the output includes every object ID. If I omitted those rows, IDs 1 and 4 would not appear in the output, at least as implemented currently. In my real case, the table is generated by a separate `LEFT JOIN`, which leaves those nulls.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you are trying to achieve: you have most of the recursive queries figured out but somehow failed where it was the easiest:

1. The initialization of your CTE could be easier with `WHERE depended_upon IS NULL`.
2. I did not understand why you had put `WHERE deletion_order.obj_id IS NULL` in the recursive part of the CTE.
3. The `JOIN` should be an inner join, I did not understand why you thought you needed an outer join (I guess it is linked with the previous point but that did not help me understand).

Resulting query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE deletion_order(obj_id, step) AS (
    SELECT obj_id, 0
    FROM dependencies
    WHERE depended_upon IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dependencies.obj_id, step + 1
    FROM dependencies
    JOIN deletion_order ON dependencies.depended_upon = deletion_order.obj_id
)
SELECT obj_id, MAX(step) AS MaxStep /*, MIN(step) AS MinStep (optional, see comment below)*/
FROM deletion_order
ORDER BY MaxStep;
```

So I do not know how to answer your question (How to avoid outer join) because you should not have felt the need to use an outer join in the first place.

I have answered a previous question as how to build a recursive CTE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74683419/how-to-write-recursive-union-alls-in-psql/74683454#74683454). Maybe it is worth checking.

Comment: This very helpful, thank you! I noticed that the output can include the same object listed multiple times, at different steps. In my example, the output includes `(3, 1)` *and* `(3,2)`. However, this is easily fixed in the outer query with a `MAX(step)`. It seems that the CTE you've provided answers the question "at what step(s) is a dependent of a given object deleted?" rather than "at what step does a given object have no remaining dependents?"

Comment: Ohh right, I got confused and took your result table as the source...  But with a `MAX(step)` as you pointed out, I get the very output you are looking for. Not sure what your last sentence means though. Is it like: "without the `MAX`, then the result of your query is different"? I would say we can add `MIN(step)` right next to the `MAX` if it is.